# is it possible to get the protect attribute when using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to using selenium `"selenium==4.15.2"` to do some automatic test, when I using this code to get the cloudflare turnstile token value attribute, it always return '', this is the python(`Python 3.10`) code look like:

```
def get_token_value(self, local_base_case: BaseCase, retries: int, we: WebElement):
    if retries > 30:
        return
    res_filter = "//input[contains(@name,'cf-turnstile-response')]"
    driver: seleniumbase.undetected.Chrome = local_base_case.driver
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    resp_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, res_filter)))
    if resp_element:
        input_element = driver.find_element(value=res_filter, by=By.XPATH)
        # this line to get the value of token, but return ''
        cf_token_value = input_element.get_attribute("value")
        if cf_token_value is None:
            self.open_the_form_turnstile_page(sb=local_base_case)
        else:
            print(cf_token_value)
    else:
        sleep(3)
        new_reties = retries + 1
        self.get_token_value(local_base_case=local_base_case, retries=new_reties, we=we)
```

the html element look like this(we can see demo div from https://seleniumbase.io/apps/turnstile):

```
<input type="hidden" name="cf-turnstile-response" id="cf-chl-widget-bfst0_response" value="0.t6oJjPnRoJG1qRdWPmWnK8WGYKiCrtWYcL-h6c_7fR5RPEEdTigemVBaANSS3chCvdAc7hNUIZBCpWgSCegIOkfY0_YvX59qVQHi5uCn9oHhtzUWv8Kp_kBLnXhGKb4xZ_EpP0BZoazRIKseoALol-KeqEORLIquN2_e4Ut6Uozb.etf9TEhNV-aU10SR2HeP9Q.7b872176c0a92432aaa1b52f8a48c45164019dd165de122fe385e7a876e1c0e6">
```

when I check the element value in PyCharm, seem these value are protected:

[image]

is it possible to get the protect attributes when using selenium? what should I do to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Try sendkeys(),  is a method in Selenium that allows QAs to type content automatically into an editable field while executing any tests.